# Is it possible to get the operands from a FuncVarPtg in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to compute a slice (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing) of an Excel Spreadsheet starting from some cell. That means I need to find out what cells are referenced in a cell and recursively follow those references. So far so good.

Now I ran into a problem with if statements (and I assume other more complex statements too) in that I get a Ptg of type FuncVarPtg, for which I don't know how to get the operands and the references contained in them.

FormulaParser.parse("IF(C2>D2,A1,B1)") yields the cells referenced in the *if condition*, but not the ones in the *then* and *else* branches. Here is some exemplary output (cell C2 holds value 1.0 and cell D2 holds 0.0, i.e. these references are resolved and followed without a problem using RefPtg.getRow() and RefPtg.getColumn())

```
fromCell IF(C2>D2,A1,B1)
ptg org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.RefPtg [C2]
fromCell 1.0
ptg org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.RefPtg [D2]
fromCell 0.0
ptg org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.FuncVarPtg [IF nArgs=3]
```

My question in short: Is there a way to get the referenced operands out of a FuncVarPtg?

Comment: I have worked around it by extracting each operand explicitely and passing it to FormulaParser.parse(). I am still interested if there's a solution via FuncVarPtg.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask on the [POI dev list](http://poi.apache.org/mailinglists.html) for help, there's a wider range of POI experts there than here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, my mistake was that I assumed POI would handle this differently. It is not needed to access the FuncVarPtg in order to get the nested operands (and in turn RefPtgs and AreaPtgs which I need for my application). FormulaParser.parse() returns an array of all the Ptgs (including the nested ones) appearing in the formula. So, for my application it is sufficient to filter that array for RefPtgs and AreaPtgs.